# Entity Framework DbSet<TEntity>.Where(e => true) performance

Tags: c#, database, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 to access a database.

Is there a performance difference between the following two methods?

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
        return context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

and

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
        return context.Set<TEntity>().Where(e => true).ToList();
}
```

I am asking because I would like to use conditional predicates. Something like this the following.

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(TKey fKey)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
        return context.Set<TEntity>()
                      .Where(e => fKey != null ? e.fKey == fKey : true).ToList();
}
```

where `fKey` would be a foreign key.

**Update**: Since many comments focus on my last example, that I agree is a bad use case, I will explain why I am asking.

So I have repository method that looks something like the following.

```
public class EntityRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Entity> GetAll(Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
            return context.Set<Entity>.Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
}
```

And I am using this method form a Web API controller's action-method. Something like the following.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetEntities(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
    Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> predicate = e =>
         (param1 != null ? e.field1 == param1 : true)
         && (param2 != null ? e.field2 == param2 : true)
         && (param3 != null ? e.field3 == param3 : true);
    var entities = EntityRepository.GetAll(predicate);
    return Ok(entities);
}
```

So here I get some query parameters from the URI and I create the predicate based on them. Some of these parameters can be `null` in which case I don't want to filter on those. But I don't want to create a different predicate for all the combinations of the parameters being `null`s or not.

I know I could read the entire set and filter one-by-one afterwards, but that would use a lot of memory with big data sets.

**So just to clarify my question**: Is this a right approach? If all 3 parameters are `null` (in which case the entire set will be returned) does this method cause any performance setbacks?

Comment: If you *know* that `fkey` is null, why use it *at all*? Just don't add it to the expression. As for performance, it depends on the *SQL query* and the execution plan generated. The first two queries will probably create the same SQL or equivalent execution plans. The third one won't, it will create a catch-all query that often results in bad execution plans

Comment: Looks like you're trying to implement the generic repository *anti*pattern on top of a higher-level ORM like Entity Framework. Check `DbSet<T>`. What does your own class offers that DbSet doesn't? If your class is just a thin wrapper, *why* do you use it at all? *Entities* have no foreign keys, they have relations and navigation properties. If your "repository" doesn't understand that, if it can't take advantage of the relations because it's "generic", it causes harm for no real benefit. It *lowers* the abstraction level below that offered by EF or any other ORM

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I can see that my bad example caused some confusion, so please check my update!

Comment: There is no confusion. Catch-all queries are simply bad. Yes, the nulls cause performance issues because they can cause the wrong execution plan to be cached and reused. Jesse shows that you don't need them in the first place when using LINQ. [This article explains](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) why catch-all queries are bad

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about performance, but you can get around the question all together by building the query before you execute. I think this improves code readability and reduces confusion as well.

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(TKey fKey)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = context.Set<TEntity>();

        if (fKey != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(e => e.fKey == fKey);
        }

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Calling your question edit, I think the following method would have the same usage, but avoids unnecessary statements in the sql queries:

```
public IEnumerable<Entity> GetAll(
    Func<IQueryable<Entity>, IQueryable<Entity>> query)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
        return query(context.Set<Entity>).ToList();
}

// then use like this:
EntityRepository.GetAll((entities) =>
    {
        var query = entities;
        if (param1 != null) query = query.Where(e => e.field1 == param1);
        if (param2 != null) query = query.Where(e => e.field2 == param2);
        if (param3 != null) query = query.Where(e => e.field3 == param3);
        return query;
    });
```

Comment: It also improves performance. `fKey != null ? e.fKey == fKey : true` would be translated to SQL generating a query whose (cached) execution plan would depend on fkey's value the first time it executed. That's a 50% chance that the *wrong* execution plan would get generated, eg one that scanned a table instead of using an index seek

Comment: I expect this won't work with a simple `var` because `context.Set<>` and `.Where()` have different result types. Probably `IQueryable<TEntity> query = ... ` would work.

Comment: I completely agree that this would be a better solution for my example, but my first questions still stands. I further explained why I would use it in my question update.

Comment: @DánielTarsoly I guess Panagiotis Kanavas's comments answer that question.